# “There has been an error while loading the form.” when open infopath2010 form

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, item-level-permissions

Form Template working fine for users. But there is one user group that when click list items this error occurs. Error details are below :

There has been an error while loading the form.
Click Try Again to attempt to load the form again. If this error persists, contact the support team for the Web site.

Click Close to exit this message.
Hide error details
The following location is in a different site collection: https://portal.x.x/FormServerTemplates/XTemplate.xsn. Access to locations on different site collections is blocked for security reasons. For more information, contact your site administrator

I think it is permission issue but i give permission where need to be given again get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Rechecked all the connection inside the form, because form is reading data from the first form so after some modification on first form, the second form could not load.